# cannot parse sentence using stanford parser even i have set environment variables

Tags: python-3.x, stanford-parser

I am using `python 3.5`.

I downloaded the Stanford parser and extracted it. I have also set the environment variable properly and it got set properly. But when I ran a sentence and tried to parse I am getting an error.

This is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#15>", line 1, in <module>
    sp.parse("this is a sentence".split())
  File "C:\Users\MAHESH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\nltk\parse\api.py", line 45, in parse
    return next(self.parse_sents([sent], *args, **kwargs))
  File "C:\Users\MAHESH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\nltk\parse\stanford.py", line 120, in parse_sents
    cmd, '\n'.join(' '.join(sentence) for sentence in sentences), verbose))
  File "C:\Users\MAHESH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\nltk\parse\stanford.py", line 216, in _execute
    stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
  File "C:\Users\MAHESH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\nltk\internals.py", line 134, in java
    raise OSError('Java command failed : ' + str(cmd))
OSError: Java command failed : ['java.exe', '-mx1000m', '-cp', 'C:/Users/MAHESH/stanfordparser/stanford-parser-full-2015-04-20\\stanford-parser-3.5.2-models.jar;C:/Users/MAHESH/stanfordparser/stanford-parser-full-2015-04-20\\ejml-0.23.jar;C:/Users/MAHESH/stanfordparser/stanford-parser-full-2015-04-20\\stanford-parser-3.5.2-javadoc.jar;C:/Users/MAHESH/stanfordparser/stanford-parser-full-2015-04-20\\stanford-parser-3.5.2-models.jar;C:/Users/MAHESH/stanfordparser/stanford-parser-full-2015-04-20\\stanford-parser-3.5.2-sources.jar;C:/Users/MAHESH/stanfordparser/stanford-parser-full-2015-04-20\\stanford-parser.jar', 'edu.stanford.nlp.parser.lexparser.LexicalizedParser', '-model', 'edu/stanford/nlp/models/lexparser/englishPCFG.ser.gz', '-sentences', 'newline', '-outputFormat', 'penn', '-tokenized', '-escaper', 'edu.stanford.nlp.process.PTBEscapingProcessor', '-encoding', 'utf8', 'C:\\Users\\MAHESH\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\tmp1jcjvrl1']
```

Comment: The last line of the error shows the command that is failing.  You should try and run it to debug what is wrong.